# TotalJSHeapSize & UsedJSHeapSize will be failed with mozjs-45 in Cobalt 11.62465

Tags: cobalt

After it upgraded to `Cobalt 11.62465`, both `TotalJSHeapSize` & `UsedJSHeapSize` test  would be failed in the `DOM CharData/Windows/Etc` catalogue with https://qual-e.appspot.com/ test. But when change the `mozjs-45` to `mozjs` in the gyp_configuration.gypi, it will be passed. So it seemed to be releated the mozjs version.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the report. This is a known issue. As Cobalt 11 is under active development, this will be fixed soon.

Comment: We fixed this internally. This will be pushed to open source in the next push. (no determined date yet)